# Illegal URI Redirect for Spotipy API

Tags: python, spotipy

I've been looking for solutions but haven't found one that works. I have checked that the environmental variables are correct and match the one that is in the Spotify developer app.

```py
import os 
import json
import time
import spotipy
import lyricsgenius as lg

spotify_client_id = os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID']
spotify_secret = os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET']
spotify_redirect = os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] 
#genius_token = os.environ['GENIUS_ACESS_TOKEN']
scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'

#spotify object
credentials = spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=spotify_client_id,
                                    client_secret=spotify_secret,
                                    redirect_uri=spotify_redirect,
                                    state=None,
                                    scope=scope,
                                    cache_path=None)

#want something from it
get_token = credentials.get_access_token()
```

Comment: And what is your problem... ?

Comment: When trying to get the access token it opens up a browser and says "Illegal URI Redirect" and I am not able to give authorization or get the token itself.